# Purescript-Pux: How to add a react component as property to another react component (Material-UI)

Tags: purescript, purescript-pux

Some libraries like material-ui require to add components as properties to another react component.

JSX Example (See [live/complete](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog)):

```
render() {
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
    label="Cancel"
    primary={true}
    onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
    label="Submit"
    primary={true}
    keyboardFocused={true}
    onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
    ];

    return (
      <div>
    <RaisedButton label="Dialog" onTouchTap={this.handleOpen} />
    <Dialog
      title="Dialog With Actions"
      actions={actions}
      modal={false}
      open={this.state.open}
      onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
    >
      The actions in this window were passed in as an array of React objects.
    </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I wonder if this is possible in purescript-pux. The following approach does not work. Is there a way which works?

```
foreign import raisedButtonClass :: ? props. ReactClass props
raisedButton = reactClassWithProps raisedButtonClass "RaisedButton"
foreign import dialogClass :: ? props. ReactClass props
dialog  = reactClassWithProps dialogClass "Dialog"

...

dialog {
    -- the next line does not work
    actions: [(raisedButton {label: "Close"} #! onClick (const ToggleDialog) $ mempty)],
    open: state.isDialogOpen,
    title: "Dialog Title"
  }
  #! (on "onRequestClose" (const ToggleDialog))
  $ text "Dialog Text"
```

You can find a complete example here: https://github.com/shybyte/pux-starter-app-material-ui/blob/master/src/Main.purs